# SSIS 2008 Column has a null value

Tags: vb.net, ssis, migration

I am currently working on an SSIS package that we are migrating from SSIS 2005 to SSIS 2008.

The issue is that the developers of the current version used the fact that in SSIS 2005 the accessor of a NULL column returns 0, whereas SSIS 2008 throws an exception.

Also, they extensively use expressions such as this one:

```
IIf(Row.X_IsNull, System.DBNull.Value, Row.X)
```

The problem is that in SSIS 2008, regardless of whether the condition is set to true, the program still tries to read Row.X and throws an exception.

The package is big and it would take a very long time to convert all of these IIfs to manual Ifs with temporary variables.

Any help would be really appreciated,

PM

Comment: what do you mean by accessor what context?
Are you speaking strictly in a script component? I'm sure I know what you are talking about but need a little more info.

Comment: Any chance you can change the source queries to return default values instead of NULLs? That might be quicker than finding all the places that fail.

Answer (score 1):

Save the package as a file. This is an XML file.  find the code you are looking to change in a text editor and pull out the pertinant parts to search for later. In BIDS, make the first fix and resave the file. You can then open the file up in a text editor  and find the other instances of the problem (you know what to look for from your perusal of the earlier file) and replace them with the same kind of code your fix generated in the file. SAve, Then open up in BIDS and test.